# getting all buttons to work from a loop

Tags: java, for-loop, jbutton, actionlistener

I am trying to find out how to get every button to give me the message of how many days it's left for christmas. the buttons is made in a for-loop, so the tricky part here for me is to open the buttons after they are made.

```
int days = 24;
int i = 1;
JButton b1 = new JButton();
JLabel l1 = new JLabel("welcome to this year advent calendar");

public Oblig6(){
    this.add(l1);
    this.setTitle("advent calender");
    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    this.setSize(230, 440);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    for(i=1; i < 25;i++){
        b1.setText("Hatch "+i);
        this.add(b1);
        b1.setVisible(true);
        b1 = new JButton();
        b1.addActionListener(this); 
    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(arg0.getSource().equals(b1)){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "it's only "+i+" days left for christmes");
    }
}}
```

Comment: store the buttons in an array, the reference that array later.

Comment: You arent creating a button 25 times. You are renaming the same button 25 times. You should create the buttons, store them in an array and give them the text at the time of creation.

Comment: You have some fundamental misunderstandings of how Java and Swing work. If this is for a class, you should show this to your teacher. If you're trying to self-learn, you should concentrate on working through more swing tutorials

Comment: @Aggressor There are 24 buttons being created but the first button does not have an action listener attached to it (look t the 4th line in the for loop).

Comment: You're right I missed that at the end. Very strange way of writting it! Esp. since he created a member variable for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to refer to the buttons later then keep an array of them instead of using just one variable (`b1`) for the last one created.  Also, you miss calling `b1.addActionListener(this)` on the first button because it's already been replaced by the next one. You can define an array of buttons like this:

`private JButton[] buttons = null;`

Then during initialization:

```
buttons = new JButton[24];
for (int i=0; i<24; i++) {
    buttons[i] = new JButton();
    buttons[i].setActionListener(this);
    buttons[i].setText("Hatch "+(i+1));
    buttons[i].setVisible(true);
    this.add(buttons[i]);
}
```

Later you can access any of the buttons through the `buttons` variable if you need.

Comment: one last question, how can i get the list number from the button. so i can say the number of days left to xmas?

Comment: That is bad design practice. You should look at model-view-controller programming. A view shouldn't know logic nor calculate it. You should store values like that in an associated dictionary or create a wrapper class that keeps track of the data

Comment: @elektronet if you have a button (from receiving an action event for example) you can find its number with a for-loop like this `int n=0; for (; n<buttons.length; n++) { if (buttons[n] == button) break; }` and at the end of the loop `n` will be the button number.